# Delete files with no permissions (read, write and execute)

Tags: command-line, permissions, delete

I have a repertory named `data` with multiple files that have different type of permissions.
Some of them have no permissions at all like `----------`.

I want to delete files based on their permissions. I only need to delete the files with no permissions in that folder nothing else. Is there a one command line to help me do this?

I tried `chmod -R 777 data` but that only rewrites all the permissions on that repertory.

Answer (score 1):

Within your `data` directory you can find a list of these files AND delete then easily.

This will return the list of files matching a "no access" permissions scheme for the file:

```
find . -type f -perm 000
```

(Translated into understandable terms, the 'find' command searches the current directory you are in `.` for files (`type -f`) to which your user executing the search has no permissions on)

Appending `-exec rm {} \;` to the end may remove the files.  However, make sure the files you find from the first command without the `exec` arg appended doesn't list files you need to keep (like git repository tracking data).

```
find . -type f -perm 000 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

... **but be careful using a recursive deletion like this** because you could delete things you *need* to have, and this will NOT prompt you before deleting each file - it'll just do it.

**Note that if your user is not the owner of the files you will not be able to delete the files**, so this will only work if your user is actually owner of those files.

Comment: Without `-type f` this will also list directories with no permissions.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog except... I don't have `-type f` anywhere in my commands... so I think you're adding things that don't actually exist here.

Comment: I didn't say that you have it. I'm saying that if you don't add it, directories will be listed too. The OP says that they want to delete **files** without permissions.

Comment: Also, in your revision about also deleting directories, will `rm -r` work for directories containing many items without the `-f` flag?

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog it will still prompt.  But I'm removing the directories revision since OP only asked about files.  And I omitted `-f` intentionally from the `rm` call because that way OP can review each item before deletion.  The post has been adjusted.